# Missing bytes in SQL Server data page

Tags: sql-server, dbcc, data-paging

Did not know how to call the Title properly. However, I am trying to understand how the data pages are stored. I've created simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE testFix
(
 id INT,
 v CHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.testFix
(
    id,
    v
)
VALUES
(   1, -- id - int
    'asdasd' -- v - varchar(100)
) 
GO 2
DBCC TRACEON(3604);
```

Then I got PageFID and PagePID by following command:

```
DBCC IND(tempdb, testFix, -1)
GO
```

Then the actual data pages:

```
DBCC PAGE (tempdb, 1, 368, 3)
```

So now I see:

> Slot 0 Offset 0x60 Length 21
>
> Record Type = PRIMARY_RECORD        Record Attributes =  NULL_BITMAP
>   Record Size = 21
>
> Memory Dump @0x000000287DD7A060
>
> 0000000000000000:   10001200 01000000 61736461 73642020 20200200 
>   ........asdasd    .. 0000000000000014:   00
>   .
>
> Slot 0 Column 1 Offset 0x4 Length 4 Length (physical) 4
>
> id = 1
>
> Slot 0 Column 2 Offset 0x8 Length 10 Length (physical) 10
>
> v = asdasd
>
> Slot 1 Offset 0x75 Length 21
>
> Record Type = PRIMARY_RECORD        Record Attributes =  NULL_BITMAP
>   Record Size = 21
>
> Memory Dump @0x000000287DD7A075
>
> 0000000000000000:   10001200 01000000 61736461 73642020 20200200 
>   ........asdasd    .. 0000000000000014:   00
>   .
>
> Slot 1 Column 1 Offset 0x4 Length 4 Length (physical) 4
>
> id = 1
>
> Slot 1 Column 2 Offset 0x8 Length 10 Length (physical) 10
>
> v = asdasd
>
> Slot 2 Offset 0x8a Length 21
>
> Record Type = PRIMARY_RECORD        Record Attributes =  NULL_BITMAP
>   Record Size = 21
>
> Memory Dump @0x000000287DD7A08A
>
> 0000000000000000:   10001200 01000000 61736461 73642020 20200200 
>   ........asdasd    .. 0000000000000014:   00

So the length of the record is 21 byte. However INT is 4 bytes and CHAR(10) is 10 bytes. 4+10=14. What for the other 7 bytes are used?

Comment: [Metadata](http://aboutsqlserver.com/2013/10/15/sql-server-storage-engine-data-pages-and-data-rows/). Two tag bytes, two bytes for the data length, two bytes for the column count, one byte for the null bitmap.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127405/sum-of-datalengths-not-matching-table-size-from-sys-allocation-units

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the "anatomy" of data row

[image]

In red there are 7 bytes you are missing: Status Bits A (1), Status Bits B (1), Fdata length (2), Ncols (2), NullBits (1)

From this book: [Pro SQL Server Internals by Korotkevitch D.](http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781430259633)